# Update table as same table in another database changes

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-trigger

I have two databases in one instance of SQL server and they have the same structure.
Now I want to write some triggers for some of the tables in databases to get synced with each other whenever they got inserted, updated or deleted records.

something like below will be going to be one of the triggers :

```
CREATE TRIGGER AdminMessage_Insert
ON AdminMessage
AFTER INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO SecondDb.dbo.AdminMessage
        ( ID ,
          DeptKey ,
          AdminKey ,
          ReceiverKey ,
          MessageText ,
          IsActive
        )
SELECT i.ID, i.DeptKey, i.AdminKey, i.ReceiverKey, i.MessageText, i.IsActive
FROM INSERTED i
```

so my problem is that there are many tables and writing about three triggers for each of them doesn't seem to be the best solution.

can you give me a better and smaller approach?

**UPDATE**

I found some ways like *CDC*, *Change Tracking*, *SQL Audit* And of course *Replication* (snap replication) and read about them. 
as I understand the best solution for me is using 'CDC' Or 'Audit'. 
in both of them, I must work with each table one by one that takes a long time from me.

can I have all table changes with less work and with one SQL instance? (replication is good, but it needs more than one instance)

what's your idea?

Comment: If you thinking about linking one trigger to more than one table, you **Can not**.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I just looking for another way than using triggers.

Comment: what do you mean by this `doesn't seem to be the best solution`

Comment: Do you need the synchronization to go both ways, or is one database the master and the other is a slave?

Comment: @redsI mean this way I must create too many triggers and I'm looking to do it in another way.

Comment: @zoharpeled yes. one of them is master and the other one is the slave.

Comment: Then you should probably use [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

While Change Data Capture (CDC) wasn't designed to be used as a sort of replication, we use it in this way at my company because it works for us. You enable CDC for the specific tables that you need to only get the net changes. The records are then stored in a database created by CDC. From there you can push the changes to the other database. You can find more information about CDC [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server).

Comment: I read the documents you referenced and seems a good way of doing my job. I found that *replication* is a good way too. can anyone say which of them is better?

Comment: I can't really say which way is better since each situation is unique. We have specific requirements where data has to stop being replicated at a certain point in time, which is why we decided to go with CDC. You have to decide what exactly is best for your requirements. If you just need data replicated then you can use either of the two to accomplish this.

Comment: +1 for your offer about *CDC*. but there is a problem in CDC for me that I must work with each table separately when I want to enable CDC on them and after that get changes from them. I look for a way to get changes for the whole database at once.

Answer (score 1):

Because it seems like you are looking for a solution that is only replicating the data one way, can I assume that the second source is read-only?  If so, and because you said both databases are on the same instance, you can use [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your secondary database.